# Why the Tensile modulus is always larger than Tensile strength?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials

I can't figure out this huge difference in values between these two mechanical material properties. When its refer to flexural strength and modulus there's a difference in value (if the material is not isotropic or homogeneous), but not quite significant as the first two.

Comment: Think about what the definitions mean. For a linear elastic material, if the tensile modulus was numerically equal to the tensile strength, the material would break when you stretched it to double its original length. Most engineering materials break long before they stretch as much as that, and the ones that do stretch a lot start to have a nonlinear stress-strain curve long before they break.

Comment: This strikes me as a little like asking ‘why is my weight so much larger than my height’. Tensile modulus and tensile strength are measuring two totally different properties of the material, as partially evidenced by their different units.